# running two interdependent while loops in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, parallel-processing

For a web-scraping analysis I need two loops that run permanently, one returning a list with websites updated every x minutes, while the other one analyses the sites (old an new ones) every y seconds. This is the code construction that exemplifies, what I am trying to do, but it doesn't work: **Code has been edited to incorporate answers and my research**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time, random

from threading import Lock
from collections import deque

class MyQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = deque()
        self.lock = Lock()

    def put(self, item):
        with self.lock:
            self.items.append(item)
# Example pointed at in [this][1] answer
    def get(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.items.popleft()

def a(queue):
    while True:
        x=[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]
        print 'send', x
        queue.put(x)
        time.sleep(10)


def b(queue):
    try:
        while queue:
            x = queue.get()
            print 'recieve', x
            for i in x:
                print i
            time.sleep(2)
    except IndexError:
        print queue.get()   



if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = MyQueue()
    p1 = Process(target=a, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=b, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

So, this is my first Python project after an online introduction course and I am struggling here big time. I understand now, that the functions don't truly run in parallel, as b does not start until a is finished ( I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045587/2822564) answer an tinkered with the timer and while True). **EDIT:** Even after using the approach given in the answer, I think this is still the case, as the `queue.get()` throws an IndexError saying, the deque is empty. I can only explain that with process a not finishing, because when I print queue.get()
immediately after .put(x) it is not empty.

I eventually want an output like this:

```
send [3,4,6]
3
4
6
3
4
send [3,8,6,5] #the code above gives always 3 entries, but in my project 
3              #the length varies
8
6
5
3
8
6
.
.
```

What do I need for having two truly parallel loops where one is returning an updated list every x minutes which the other loop needs as basis for analysis? Is Process really the right tool here? 
And where can I get good info about designing my program.

Comment: Thread is definitely the easiest answer to your problem ! It could be scary but it is quite easy to do in Python

Comment: @Lordofdark I will take that advice and read up on threads, too! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something a little like this a while ago. I think using the Process is the correct approach, but if you want to pass data between processes then you should probably use a Queue.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Create the queue first and pass it into both processes. One can write to it, the other can read from it.

One issue I remember is that the reading process will block on the queue until something is pushed to it, so you may need to push a special 'terminate' message of some kind to the queue when process 1 is done so process 2 knows to stop.

EDIT: Simple example. This doesn't include a clean way to stop the processes. But it shows how you can start 2 new processes and pass data from one to the other. Since the queue blocks on get() function b will automatically wait for data from a before continuing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time, random

def a(queue):
    while True:
        x=[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]
        print 'send', x
        queue.put(x)
        time.sleep(5)


def b(queue):
    x = []
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            x = queue.get(False)
            print 'receive', x
        except:
            pass
        for i in x:
            print i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=a, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=b, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, first of all. I been reading up on queues and tried to play with it. I can't get your example to work, though.  I get an `TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable`.And isn't a q=Queue.Queue() or something missing? I saw that in an example.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a few minor mistakes. I've updated the example, and actually run the code this time.

Comment: this is really good! But I still have one major problem left: Your code prints out `i in x` only once. A while loop in front of `for i in x`  prints it out continuously, but does not accept the new queue.get().  So I get `receive [new list]` but `print i` still prints the old list. In my real life project function 1 delivers a changing list of URL's, which function 2 needs to analyze continuously, being 'receptive' to new inputs on the list. What is the right construction for this?

Comment: I update the answer. The solution is to tell the queue.get clall to not block. If there's nothing in the queue it will raise an error, which you can catch and handle (by ignoring it and continuing with the existing data)

Comment: My answer assumes that you are using the special Queue from the multiprocessing module that is already process/thread safe and includes the necessary functionality.

Comment: Great news, thank you! I will give that a go. I am currently also looking into using celery… a lot of new things to get my head around, so please bare with me before I close this question as answered.