# parallel, interdependent processes - how to push variables across?

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing

This is a follow-up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137605/running-two-interdependent-while-loops-in-python) question, if it's of any interest.

To spare you from reading it, here is the sum-up:
I have two processes, that both need to run indefinitely.

I need Process 1 to scan a website for specific URLs like every 10 minutes or so. These URLs are stored in a SetQueue, so I don't have double entries. Every loop will produce a certain amount of URLs. After the first run, most will be already stored, but there will also be a few new ones, which also need to be stored in the queue.

Process 2 receives a list, that results from the queue and scrapes the URLs continuously every 10 seconds to check for changing AJAX-values.

The problem I need help with, is how to make Process 2 receive the updated list while it is running in a different frequency than Process 1.

Here is my code model of the process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time, random

def a(queue):
    while True:
        x=[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]
        print 'send', x
        queue.put(x)
        time.sleep(20)


def b(queue):
    x = queue.get()
    print 'recieve', x
    while True:        
        for i in x:
            print i
            time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=a, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=b, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The model has one big issue, I cannot solve: How to make Process b receive the updated list? In comparison to the answer I received in the cited question, I have placed the while loop in front of the iteration `for i in x:` as this gives me a continuing processing loop I want. But naturally, all new input from process a is ignored.
I am sure, this is a very easy problem for 'real' programmers, but I can't find a solution here. Any help is appreciated. Should I even keep using Process for this?

Comment: Sounds like it's a task for Celery.

Comment: Forgot to add, Celery does not support Windows.

Comment: I will try that, I run on Mac, so Celery might work. Thanks!

Comment: @postoronnim  I use celery now, but can't get my worker thread to repeat, so I have the same issue still. what's the protocol here, can I just edit the question or open a new one?

Comment: @ user2822564 if it's now a celery issue, asking it under it's own topic would give you a better chance of getting an answer, gl!